# Run Apache2 server and XAMPP on same machine (Ubuntu)

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, apache2, lampp

I have XAMPP installed on my machine. Additionally, I have also installed apache2 as a stand-alone web server. How do I run both on the server independently?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure they listen to different ports.

`XAMPP:
    Listen 80
APACHE2：
    Listen 90`

Comment: How do I achieve this ? In which file the changes are to be made ?

Comment: My advice: Apache is a component of xampp, if repeated install them, may be caused by the conflict, so you'd better compile an new Apache, installed in a different directory, such as `/usr/local/apache2_4`, and modify the following items in the configuration file : `Listen XX`, `DocumentRoot /XXX` to what you want